# Redux - Is there any way to access store tree in reducer?

Tags: redux

In my case, I have a store like:

```
{
  aa: {...},
  bb: cc  // the result of computing with aa
}
```

I need to update `aa` and `bb` at the same time, but `bb` need to get the latest computation of `aa`.

Here is some code(React.js):

```
onClick(e) {
  const { dispatch, aa, bb } = this.props;

  dispatch(updateAa());
  dispatch(updateBb(aa)); // can not get the latest computation of aa, it is the last computation..
}
```

So, is this mean that I need to get `aa` in `bb`'s reducer?

And How can I do it?

Hope for helps!, Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are several possibilities, but it's tough to say which is best, given the vagueness of the code.

- Ideally, [your store should be normalized](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html), meaning that each piece of data is only available in one place. Then you would calculate derived data *after* reading the store, such as when you use the [selector pattern](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html) described in the guide to map the state of the store to what you might consider a materialized view that will be sent to your components as `props`. In this workflow, `aa` and `bb` would each be produced by selector functions, rather than stored in that store itself.
- You could leave the reducer that updates `aa` and `bb` outside of `combineReducers`, so that it sees the whole state, rather than the state scoped down to `aa` and `bb`.
- You could factor out your calculation code into a helper that could be called by `updateAa` and `updateBb`, and pass enough info in each action to make the calculation.
- You could calculate the update before dispatching, so that the action contains the right value.

Answer (score 45):

don't use `combineReducers.`

**Example**

replace this code

```
export const a = combineReducers({
  app,
  posts,
  intl,
  products,
  pos,
  cats,
});
```

with

```
export default (state = {}, action) => {
  return {
    app: app(state.app, action, state),
    posts: posts(state.posts, action, state),
    intl: intl(state.intl, action, state),
    products: products(state.products, action, state),
    pos: pos(state.pos, action, state),
    cats: cats(state.cats, action, state),
  };
};
```

reducer would be like

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action, root) => {....}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Very useful. If you could provide a simple explanation of how and why this works it'd be more helpful

Comment: Actually `combineReducer` internally calls your reducers with two parameters, `reducer's state` and `action`. As we get rid off  `combineReducer` and Our explicit calls are with an extra parameter. That is our root state. If you see example above, beside reducer's state `state.app`, we are passing `state` as third parameter which is our root state. Hope this explanation would be helpful to you @chidimo

Comment: Sure it is. Thanks.

Comment: I had to do it like this because I use `history` and `connected-react-router`:
```

Answer (score 12):

As David L. Walsh said, probably you should structure your reducers in a more logical way.

**BUT** If you still think you need it, you can use a thunk Middleware.
(https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)
Redux Thunk middleware allows you to write action creators that return a function instead of an action.

Redux Thunk offers you a way to read the current state of the Redux store. In addition to dispatch, it also passes getState as the second argument to the function you return from your thunk action creator.

```
export function action() {
    return function(dispatch, getState){
        const state = getState()
        dispatch({
            type: "ACTION_WITH_SOME_PART_OF_STATE,
            some_part_of_state: state.some_part
        })   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Ask yourself whether you've structured your reducers correctly. If a and b are not independent of one another, why are they separate reducers? I would try to merge them into a single reducer.

Comment: Good call, I will add this idea to my list to make it more comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Sheikh Abdul Wahid's answer, I had to do the following modification to make it work with `history` and `connected-react-router`:

**Notice the `()` after the `connectRouter(history)`**

```
import { connectRouter } from 'connected-react-router'

const createRootReducer = (history) => {
  return (state = {}, action) => {
    return {
      ...reducers,
      router: connectRouter(history)(),
      ...rest of reducers
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a common use case for you, you can try writing your own function to combine reducers according to your needs, as recommended by the [official Redux documentation](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/beyond-combinereducers):

---

### Sharing data between slice reducers

Similarly, if sliceReducerA happens to need some data from sliceReducerB's slice of state in order to handle a particular action, or sliceReducerB happens to need the entire state as an argument, combineReducers does not handle that itself. This could be resolved by writing a custom function that knows to pass the needed data as an additional argument in those specific cases, such as:

```
function combinedReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'A_TYPICAL_ACTION': {
      return {
        a: sliceReducerA(state.a, action),
        b: sliceReducerB(state.b, action)
      }
    }
    case 'SOME_SPECIAL_ACTION': {
      return {
        // specifically pass state.b as an additional argument
        a: sliceReducerA(state.a, action, state.b),
        b: sliceReducerB(state.b, action)
      }
    }
    case 'ANOTHER_SPECIAL_ACTION': {
      return {
        a: sliceReducerA(state.a, action),
        // specifically pass the entire state as an additional argument
        b: sliceReducerB(state.b, action, state)
      }
    }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

---

I highly recommend you to read [this documentation page](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/beyond-combinereducers), where there are also other suggestions to share data between reducers, even using `combineReducers` for simple actions and other custom reducers for the special cases.

I hope these options help!

Answer (score 0):

You can access the other reducer's data in actions and dispatch that data as a param.

`actions.js`

```
const actionFn = (param1) => {
    return (dispatch, stateFn) => {
    const { param2 } = stateFn().other.reducer;
    dispatch({
      type: ACTION,
      param1,
      param2,
    });
  };
};
```

`reducer.js`

```
case ACTION:
    return reducerFn(state, data);

const reducerFn = (state, { param1, param2 }) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    someState: {
      ...state.riverhealth,
      setParam1: param1
      setParam2: param2,
    },
  };
};
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

If some reducer needs some data from another reducer, a simple solution is to merge them into a single reducer. 
In my case, I need some data from another reducer and it is very difficult to manage them so I ended up merging them both.